# Implement next,previous,home page,share button throughout my flutter app

Tags: flutter, dart

1.I have created a   lesson app **USING FLUTTER** in which I want to implement next,previous,share & home button in each page...How can I do this

2.I need your help

Comment: you should use pageview

Answer (score 0):

If you have a scaffold, this will have an appbar and you place the actions in the appbar with icon buttons.
A scaffold also has a body which can be a pageview which in turn, can hold your various pages.

Depending on the app, you might get the pageView or a gestureDetector to give you swipe left and right for your previous or next.

Comment: Thank you for  this answer .your answer was a light bulb moment for me ....thank you so much...